# Cordova Camera plugin gives error 'object' has no method "getPicture"

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, camera

I am working on ionic v1 Camera app after setting up everything correctly (as done many times before). after building app and debugging it i got this error. 
[image: object has no Method]

Plugin installed correctly, 
ng-cordova.min included. 
$CordovaCamera injected.
Here is my Code:

```
$scope.takePhoto = function () {
              var options = {
                quality: 100,
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
                allowEdit: true,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
                targetWidth: 300,
                targetHeight: 300,
                popoverOptions: CameraPopoverOptions,
                saveToPhotoAlbum: true
            };

                $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function (imageData) {
                    $rootScope.imgURI = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
                    $state.go('menu.signUp');
                }, function (err) {
                    // An error occured. Show a message to the user
                });
            }
```

functions are working fine. but camera is not opening and gives error 
as seen in picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with injecting $cordovaCamera in contact controller and use it like this

camera.getPicture()   //just camera instead of $cordovaCamera

Answer (score 0):

Use camera.getPicture() or navigator.camera.getPicture()

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-camera/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure $cordovaCamera dependency Injected then use it like this

```
$cordovaCamera.getPicture(options).then(function(imageData) {
  var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
  image.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
}, function(err) {
  // error
});
```